# Как корректно определить состояние команд и передавать его?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

У меня есть три команды, в которых определено условие, при котором они могут выполняться. В итоге у меня три кнопки одновременно в состоянии Enabled, либо после нажатия любой из кнопок они находятся в состоянии Disabled, так как мне нужно поле `Question` класса `StudentModel` обнулять. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии одной из них, остальные кнопки становились Disabled и это состояние кнопок передавать другим кнопкам.

Класс с св-вом, которое мне нужно делать null:

```
public class StudentModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 public ObservableCollection<string> Questions { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public static SolidColorBrush defaultColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    public SolidColorBrush AnswerColor { get; set; } = defaultColor;

    private AnswerType userAnswer;
    public AnswerType UserAnswer
    {
        get => userAnswer;
        set
        {
            userAnswer = value;
            AnswerColor = ChangeColor(value);

            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(AnswerColor));
        }
    }
    #endregion
    private string question;
    public string Question
    {
        get => question;
        set
        {
            if (question == value) return;
            question = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Question));
        }
    }

SolidColorBrush ChangeColor(AnswerType answer)
    {
        switch (answer)
        {
            case AnswerType.NotGuessed:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
            case AnswerType.Correct:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            case AnswerType.NotCorrect:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            case AnswerType.DontKnow:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
            case AnswerType.NotSet:
                return defaultColor;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Не выбран цвет!");
        }
    }
    public enum AnswerType
    {
        Correct, NotCorrect, DontKnow, NotSet, NotGuessed
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Команды из класса MainWindowViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand<StudentModel> questionCmd = null;
    public RelayCommand<StudentModel> QuestionCmd => questionCmd ?? (questionCmd = new RelayCommand<StudentModel>((param) =>
    {
        new QuestionView() { DataContext = param }.ShowDialog();
    },
        (param) =>
        {
            return (param != null && param.Questions.Count == 0) ? false : true;
        }
        ));

public RelayCommand<StudentModel> yesCmd = null;

public RelayCommand<StudentModel> YesCmd => yesCmd ?? (yesCmd = new RelayCommand<StudentModel>((param) =>
    {
        param.Question = null;
        if (OnTick != param.UpTime)
        {
            OnTick += param.UpTime;
        }
    },
    (stdParam) =>
    {
        return (stdParam != null) ? !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stdParam.Question) : false;
    }));

    public RelayCommand<StudentModel> noCmd = null;
    public RelayCommand<StudentModel> NoCmd => noCmd ?? (noCmd = new RelayCommand<StudentModel>((param) =>
    {
        param.Question = null;
        if (OnTick != param.UpTime)
        {
            OnTick += param.UpTime;
        }
    },
    (stdParam) =>
    {
        return (stdParam != null) ? !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stdParam.Question) : false;
    }));

    public RelayCommand<StudentModel> dontKnowCmd = null;
    public RelayCommand<StudentModel> DontKnowCmd => dontKnowCmd ?? (dontKnowCmd = new RelayCommand<StudentModel>((param) =>
    {
        param.Question = null;
        if (OnTick != param.UpTime)
        {
            OnTick += param.UpTime;
        }
    },
    (param) =>
    {
        return (param != null) ? !string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.Question) : false;
    }));
```

Класс команды:

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : CommandBase
{
    private readonly Action<T> _execute;
    private readonly Func<T, bool> _canExecute;
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute) : this(execute, null) { }
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Func<T, bool> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute.Invoke((T)parameter);
    public override void Execute(object parameter) { _execute.Invoke((T)parameter); }
}
```

Базовый класс команд:

```
public abstract class CommandBase : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public abstract bool CanExecute(object parameter);
    public abstract void Execute(object parameter);
}
```

XAML второго окна:

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="0" Background="Gray" Height="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Вопросы" Width="250">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="14" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Да">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Да">
                                <Button.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UserAnswerYes}" Value="Correct">
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Resources>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Нет">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Нет">
                                <Button.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UserAnswerNo}" Value="NotCorrect">
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Resources>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Не знаю">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Не знаю">
                                <Button.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UserAnswerDontKnow}" Value="DontKnow">
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Resources>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: 2 вопроса: у вас Framework или Core, и второй - покажите реализацию `RelayCommand`. И еще одно: сейчас у вас не работает?

Comment: @aepot Framework, добавил класс команды и базовый класс команды

Comment: @aepot идея такова - архив нажатий на кнопки пользователем

Comment: @aepot да, сейчас не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужны команды в дочернем окне для показа результата выбора пользователем. Заведите энумератор.

```csharp
public enum Answer
{
    Yes,
    No,
    DontKnow
}
```

Класс для хранения разных вопросов

```csharp
public class Question
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Answer CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

И класс для записи результата

```csharp
public class AnswerLog
{
    public Question Question { get; set; }
    public Answer Answer { get; set; }
}
```

Список разных вопросов

```
public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions;
```

Тогда создание вопроса будет выглядеть так

```csharp
Question question = new Question()
{
    Text = "Есть ли в C# энумераторы?",
    CorrectAnswer = Answer.Yes
}
Questions.Add(question);
```

В команду передавайте то, что содержит текущий вопрос

Тогда проверка на правильность внутри команды будет выглядеть так

```csharp
// YesCmd

// к примеру
// currentQuestion - текущий вопрос
// user.Answers - ObservableCollection<AnswerLog>
user.Answers.Add(new AnswerLog()
{
    Question = currentQuestion,
    Answer = Answer.Yes
});
if (currentQuestion.CorrectAnswer == Answer.Yes)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Правильно");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Не правильно");
}
```

Если вы перестроите логику хранения данных подобным образом, можно будет сразу показать значение правильного ответа, команды для отображения данных не служат, и у вас не получится это сделать с помощью `CanExecute`, либо это будет костыль размером с вселенную. Команды предназначены для того, чтобы что-то выполнять.

Фейковые отключенные кнопки можно и так, без команд показать, например с помощью `DataTrigger`.

```xaml
<Button Content="Yes">
    <Button.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Answer}" Value="Yes">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

А лучше вообще не кнопки, а какую-нибудь картинку с галочкой, или шрифтовую галочку в `TextBlock`, а через `DataTrigger` управлять ее свойством `Visible`.

Или вообще без наворотов текстом через конвертер

```csharp
public class AnswerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Answer answer)
        {
            switch (answer)
            {
                case Answer.Yes:
                    return "Да"; break;
                case Answer.No:
                    return "Нет"; break;
                case Answer.DontKnow:
                    return "Не знаю"; break;                   
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => null;
}
```

Подключить конвертер

```xaml
<Window.Resources>
    <local:AnswerConverter x:Key="AnswerConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

И использовать где угодно, где надо получить значение энумератора локализованным текстом

```xaml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Answer, Converter={StaticResource AnswerConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110022/discussion-on-answer-by-aepot-------).